# Unity 3D: Overlapping mesh not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I recently made this blanket in blender but when I imported it into unity part of the mesh disappeared.
In Unity (missing the overlap)

[image]

In Blender (with overlap)

[image]

I tried messing around with a bunch of setting in unity and search this up but I haven't found anything that works.

Comment: Are you sure your normals are exporting correctly?

Comment: try double sided material

Comment: Remember unity will not draw backfaces for optimisation reasons